# package nGinx impossible to download_

Tags: centos

In my CentOS 8 VM  installed on VirtualBox, I tried downloading nginx to create a DHCP server for educational purpose. however, it has returned the error message:

```
errors during downloading metadata for 'appstream':
curl (6): couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrolist.centos.org.
```

Can I have some tips to resolve this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add DNS to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
printf  "nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: thanks for helping me, however i tried that command, and it seems like i don't have a DNS file.